# Como ajustar imagem dentro da borda?

Tags: html, css

Como faço pra ajustar está imagem dentro da borda, no HTML 5.

**HTML**

```
<figure class="foto-legenda">
  <img src="_imagens/coz21web.jpg" width="830">

  <figcaption>
    <h3>Marcenaria Anderlopes</h3>
    <p>Realizando sonhos</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure.foto-legenda {

    position: relative;
    border: 8px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;}

figure.foto-legenda figcaption {

    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; }

figure.foto-legenda:hover figcaption {opacity: 1;}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Por favor, poste o código com a sua tentativa, poderemos ajudar a partir daí. Lembrando que é sempre bom dar uma lida em [ask] e se possível fazer um [tour] para entender como funciona a comunidade ;)

Comment: Coloque o seu código HTML para que seja possível um melhor entendimento à sua pergunta. Você pode usar um serviço como o [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com)

Comment: ajusta o width da imagen pra 100%, ai ajusta o width do contêiner para o tamanho que você quer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eduardo minha sugestão é que faça um CSS exclusivo para a imagem. no caso eu fiz essa classe `figure.foto-legenda img` e coloquei nela a largura de 100% e a altura automática.

Veja que agora ela ocupa a área toda. *(mande exibir tb em "Página toda" para ver que ela adapta a largura da tela)* OBS: além do css da imagem não mexi em mais nada, nem no css nem no html, apenas o css da imagem mesmo.

```css
figure.foto-legenda {
    position: relative;
    border: 8px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
}

figure.foto-legenda img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

figure.foto-legenda figcaption {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
}

figure.foto-legenda:hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foto-legenda">
  <img src="http://unsplash.it/600/200">

  <figcaption>
    <h3>Marcenaria Anderlopes</h3>
    <p>Realizando sonhos</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```